# How to escape all input to a Velocity template

Tags: java, html, escaping, velocity

We're using Apache Velocity to generate HTML, and I'd like to add my own escaping to all input to our templates -- without changing our templates. Velocity seems pretty extendable, but I'm having a hard time finding my way around the framework.

Do you know if there is some easy way to escape the input without changing all my templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through a [`ReferenceInsertionEventHandler`](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/developer-guide.html#orgapachevelocityappeventreferenceinsertioneventhandler) implementation.

> According to the [developer guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/developer-guide.html#registering-event-handlers) for Velocity 2.1: ou may
> register event handlers in either of two manners. The easiest way to
> register event handlers is to specify them in velocity.properties.
> (Event handlers configured in this manner are referred to as "global"
> event handlers). For example, the following property will escape HTML
> entities in any inserted reference.
>
> ```
> event_handler.reference_insertion.class = org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeHtmlReference
> ```

Note that `EscapeHtmlReference` is deprecated. You should provide your own implementation, which can be loaded in a similar manner.

Alternatively, the handler can be loaded through code:

```
InternalEventContext context; // eg. VelocityContext

EventCartridge eventCartridge = new EventCartridge();
if (!eventCartridge.attachToContext(context)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Velocity context does not support event cartridge");
}

eventCartridge.addReferenceInsertionEventHandler(new ReferenceInsertionEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object referenceInsert(Context context, String reference, Object value) {
        return escaper.escape(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
EventCartridge eventCartridge = new EventCartridge();
context.attachEventCartridge(eventCartridge);
eventCartridge.addReferenceInsertionEventHandler(new ReferenceInsertionEventHandler() {
  public Object referenceInsert(String reference, Object value) {
    return escaper.html(value.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: What is context in here? The ServletContext?